# Populating Columns Using SELECT Statements - Formatting Issue

Tags: postgresql, select, sql-insert

I am trying to create a new table with 2 columns. The aim is to populate the first column with a `SELECT` statement on one Postgres table and then populate the 2nd column with another `SELECT` statement on a different Postgres table.

A generalised version of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
CREATE TABLE test_db_021215(
a_hashed_email VARCHAR,
b_hashed_emailaddress VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO test_db_021215(a_hashed_email)
SELECT hashed_email FROM 123_final;
INSERT INTO test_db_021215(b_hashed_emailaddress)
SELECT hashed_emailadress FROM xyz_final;
ALTER TABLE test_db_021215
ADD COLUMN urn SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
ANALYZE test_db_021215;
```

The issue is that while the above query does populate the columns, the format is odd:

Say attribute **a_hashed_email** is fully populated with 500 records, then attribute **b_hashed_emailaddress** (say it also has 500 records) is blank from records 1 - 500 but then starts being populated from 501 - 1000.

So I end up with **a_hashed_email** populated from 1 - 500 and blank from 501 - 1000 and **b_hashed_emailaddress** blank from 1 - 500 and populated from 501 - 1000.

I have a vague memory of seeing a similar issue before but I can't for the life of me find it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You must consider inserted values into row as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this problem that might help someone else with a similar issue.

Say tables `123_final` and `xyz_final` are both produced from the same source `csv` and hence have the same row order.

By adding a `serial` attribute to each table the join can then be made based on the `serial`attribute:

```
COPY( SELECT * FROM 123_final, xyz_final WHERE 123_serial = xyz_serial )
TO '/Users/Shared/123_xyz_joined_table_all_component_attributes_180216.csv'
(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER, ENCODING LATIN1);
```

I know that there are probably much better ways of achieving this and that this is a very basic way of doing a `JOIN`, but it has produced the desired result without the weird formatting issue that I saw previously. If anyone has an alternative, better solution then please post it as it will help me to improve my SQL skills which is always a plus!

**PS.** I'm not 100% sure on the etiquette of answering your own question - I found a way to get this working that I understood and will use again in the future. If you're not meant to answer your own question then I will change this to a comment.

Thanks

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer you own question. Motivation is just as you said - to help other people. Sorry I cannot help you back in February when you wrote your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider values inserted to row as one. Since you didn't show any relation between `123_final` and `xyz_final`, and you try to insert them separately in default order of `SELECT` output I present solution to meet that criteria:

```
INSERT INTO test_db_021215(a_hashed_email, b_hashed_emailaddress)

SELECT hashed_email, hashed_emailadress
FROM
    (SELECT row_number() over() as num, hashed_email
    FROM 123_final ) as s1
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT row_number() over() as num, hashed_emailadress
                FROM xyz_final
    ) as s2 ON s1.num = s2.num;
```

Comment: @Gabriel's_Messanger - really sorry I just realised that I never replied to this - apologies that is poor form! I'll be honest, I don't fully understand your answer. I get that you are saying I need to tell Postgres how the 2 tables that I am selecting from are related but I got a bit confused following it through to the end. I have tried many variations on what you have said, just can't make it work. Do you have another worked through example or even the phrase to Google it myself as I am drawing a blank trying to replicate this? No worries if not, I know this is an old post now. Many thanks